# Problem enabling OpenGL ES depth test on iPhone. What steps are necessary?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I remember running into this problem when I started using OpenGL in OS X. Eventually I solved it, but I think that was just by using glut and c++ instead of Objective-C...

The lines of code I have in `init` for the `ES1Renderer` are as follows:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
```

Then in the `render` method, I have this:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I assume I'm missing something specific to either the iPhone or ES. What other steps are required to enable the depth test?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate the depth buffer itself.  Allocate a new renderbuffer with the internal format DEPTH_COMPONENT16 or DEPTH_COMPONENT24, and attach it to the framebuffer object.

Comment: Do you mean with something like this?
glGenRenderbuffersOES(DEPTH_COMPONENT24, &depthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_DEPTHBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
I tried to do this where the other gen and bind calls were, but neither DEPTH_COMPONENT24 (or 16) nor GL_DEPTHBUFFER_OES seem to be defined. How do you allocate and attach it?

Comment: That would be GL_ DEPTH_COMPONENT24

Answer (score 4):

The instructions are [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html), if anyone else has this problem. The code is also below:

```
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, 320, 480);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) ;
if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
    NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", status);
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're passing floats to glRenderbufferStorage ?

Comment: Most likely because I don't know what it does, and have not looked at it's documentation. =P
Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

`#define USE_DEPTH_BUFFER 1` if you're using the OpenGL ES project template.  This sets up a depth buffer somewhere in EAGLView.m.

Comment: I think this only applies to the old setup. With the new default project, USE_DEPTH_BUFFER is not used anywhere.